# Showing that a function is bounded in a neighborhood of some point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in a punctured disc $D_r(z_0) - \{z_0\}$, and suppose that

$$|f(z)| \leq A|z-z_0|^{-1+\epsilon}$$

for some $\epsilon >0$ and all $z$ near $z_0$. If I multiply both sides of the equation by $(z-z_0)$ and define $g(z) = (z-z_0)f(z)$, then why precisely (maybe pictorally?) does

$$|g(z)| \leq A |z - z_0|^{\epsilon}$$

indicate that $g(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$?

Why didn't the original inequality already demonstrate that $f(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$? Isn't $|z-z_0|^{-1+\epsilon}$ also equal to some very small number, and hence isn't $|f(z)|$ bounded as well?

Thanks.

**Followup:**

My notes say that: If $g(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then that means the singularity at $z_0$ of $g$ is removable. From this, we know that $g$ can be expressed using a power series of the form

$$g(z) = a_1(z - z_0) + a_2(z-z_0)^2 + \dots$$

which converges on $D_r(z_0)$. Hence, by factoring out $z-z_0$, we get that

$$f(z) = a_1 + a_2(z-z_0) + \dots$$

which also converges on all of $D_r(z_0)$, so the singularity of $f(z)$ at $z_0$ is also removable.

*A few questions regarding this proof:*

1. I get that $g$ can be expressed as a power series, but what does it mean for the power series to "converge on $D_r(z_0)$"?
2. Why are we allowed to simply factor out $z-z_0$?

Comment: 1. The power series converges in a disc if it converges at any point in the disc. This is usual convergence. 2. When $z \neq z_0$ you can cancel $z-z_0$ without worry, and then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ which means that $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists and is given by the same formula. 3. For this expansion of $g$ it's not enough for $g$ to be bounded, you need $\lim_{z\to z_0} |g(z)| = 0$. (Consider $g = 1$, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

For small $\epsilon > 0$, $-1+\epsilon < 0$, and so $|z-z_0|^{-1+\epsilon} \to \infty$ as $z\to z_0$. That's not true for $|z-z_0|^\epsilon$ since $\epsilon \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks -- I made edits to the OP asking a few more questions about the continuation of the proof.

Comment: Perhaps your follow-up question should be a different question.