# A problem regarding removable singularity in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving, singularity

I am reading complex analysis from Stein and Shakarchi.I am struggling with a problem given in the exercise.The problem is given below:

> Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic in a punctured disc $D_r(z_0)-\{z_0\}$.Suppose also that $|f(z)|\leq A|z-z_0|^{-1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and all $z$ near $z_0$.Show that the singularity of $f$ at $z_0$ is removable.

I have no idea how to start the problem.I think that somehow I have to use Riemann theorem on removable singularity,which states that if $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$,then $f$ has removable singularity.That means I have to show that $f$ is bounded.Can someone help me to show that provided I am on the right track.

**Addendum**

I saw similar question on stack exchange but that too had no satisfactory answer.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955050/42969

Comment: If you saw a similar question before then please add a link to that question, and tell us what you find unsatisfactory about the answer. Otherwise there is a risk that you'll get the same (unsatisfactory) answer again.

Comment: Cite the similar question you found on SE and remove the sentence "I have no idea how to start the problem." It adds nothing to the question and it is a red flag for closure. Also, look at the Wikipedia article on removable singularities, in particular [Riemann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem). The proof of that theorem will give you an idea of where to start. There are other approaches that don't require power series, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can also be done by extending the proof of Riemann’s theorem, using the multiple keyhole contour around the singularity $z_0$ and some $z$ in the domain of the punctured disk. To show that $z_0$ is removable, we want to show that $f(z)$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on the entire disk. As in the proof of Riemann’s theorem, we want to show that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z}d\xi$ is the extended holomorphic function of $f(z)$. After applying the proof of Cauchy’s integral theorem, the problem can be reduced to showing that $\left|\int_{\gamma_\eta’}\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z}d\xi\right|\to0$ as $\eta\to0$, where $\gamma_\eta’$ is the circle centered around $z_0$ of radius $\eta$ with negative orientation. You can use triangle inequality and the bound $|f(z)|\leq A|z-z_0|^{-1+\epsilon}$ to conclude the limit.

Of course, applying the fact that $|f(z)||z-z_0|\leq A|z-z_0|^\epsilon\to0$ as $z\to z_0$ is cleaner, but the equivalence to Riemann’s theorem is not shown in Stein & Shakarchi.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $|f(z) (z-z_0)|\le A|z-z_0|^{\epsilon}$, hence $f(z)(z-z_0)$ is bounded near $z_0$. Therefore $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)(z-z_0)$. And from the inequality again, $|f(z)(z-z_0)|\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow z_0$. Now we have the expansion $f(z)(z-z_0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ where $n$ starts from $1$, as the LHS is $0$ at $z=z_0$. Hence $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^{n-1}$ has analytic continuation to $z=z_0$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the lavender region,
$$
\begin{align}
f(a)
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
$\text{(1b)}$: the integral along the oppositely directed linear segments cancel
$\phantom{\text{(1b): }}$the integral along $B(z_0,\delta)$ is at most $\frac{2\pi\delta A\delta^{-1+\epsilon}}{|z_0-a|-\delta}=\frac{2\pi A\delta^{\epsilon}}{|z_0-a|-\delta}\to0$

The function defined by $\text{(1b)}$ is equal to $f$ in $B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ and is analytic in $B(z_0,r)$.

Comment: I had deleted this answer a week ago thinking that the OP would improve their question, but as they had accepted an answer, it appears there is little incentive to improve the question. The question has also passed a close review, so it appears to be okay with at least some members of the community. I did not find a duplicate, so I have undeleted my answer since I feel it is a good alternative approach.