# Problems in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I am a graduate student.I studied complex analysis in the last semester.Now I want to do some problems on complex analysis based on the theory I learnt.I mainly want to do this because I want to crack the NBHM PHD. exam.I want to practice some problems based on Liouville's theorem,uniqueness theorem,argument principle,Rouche's theorem,open mapping theorem and maximum modulus principle that are needed for the NBHM exam.The problems should be conceptual and doable.I have referred to several texts but none of them provide problems that apply these results.I have solved already the NBHM previous papers.Can someone please sugggest me some problem set or stack exchange page in which I can find problems of the kind I want?

Comment: What about the problems from the book you have mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472962/a-problem-regarding-removable-singularity-in-complex-analysis)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde There are some nice problems which I have already done,rest are not so nice.